# How can i delete a file using vnode?

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit

I am writing a kernel extention for Mac os, and i need to delete a tmp file created by 
vnode_open(),but i can not find out how to delete a file and list all files in a dir.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/vnode_h/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is better to create user-space daemon and to communicate with it using mach RPC.
The method of deletion of file in kext (that i'm aware of) depends on the version of kernel because it requires lookup of the offset of v_op (vnode operations vector. It is not visible from kernel extensions) within vnode structure. The vnode structure may change from kernel to kernel. And even if one finds vnop_remove_desc and vnop_rmdir_desc i think using it may be dangerous due to possible changes of the logic of using these callbacks.